# issue with using a Subquery with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issue while being left joining 2 tables using subquery, getting an error :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
> Incorrect syntax near 'PM'.

Here is the query I was trying to achieve:

```
SELECT 
    [SEASON],
    SUM(B.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY,
   
FROM
    (SELECT
         QUANTITY, WAREHOUSE,
         CASE SUBSTRING(sku, 3, 1)
             WHEN '1' THEN 'SS'
             ELSE 'FW'
         END + SUBSTRING (sku, 1, 2) [SEASON]
     FROM 
         Table 
    ) B
```

Comment: What is your question here, exactly?

Comment: @Larnu am having an error with my query, i don't get a result, I don't know if am doing it right with the left joint and the second subquery.

Comment: On a separate note, *good* formatting is important, you really should get in the habit of using it, as your SQL would be far more readable. Do you also have a *good* reason for using `NOLOCK`? Do you understand what it actually does? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) Also don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" and some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated.

Comment: And that error is what...?

Comment: You have `FROM` twice (for each subquery) - that won't work for sure - **ONE** `FROM`, then as many `JOIN`s as you need .....

Comment: here is the error :

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near 'PM'.

Comment: go ahead and add that error right into the question's text, not as a comment please

Comment: Your outer query has **two** `FROM` clauses, @YoussiMizrahi ... A query can only have *one* `FROM`. Perhaps that second `FROM` is meant to be a `CROSS JOIN` or `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`?

Comment: @erik258 added to the original question

Comment: @Larnu when i did remove it i got more errors, if possible would pls advice how the final Query would be, thx; if possible

Comment: I don't get any errors when I change that `FROM` to a `CROSS JOIN`, @YoussiMizrahi

Comment: @Larnu I got an error: invalid object name PRODTABLE, with all respect i think I'm not fully familiar with most of these term, that's the reason am asking for the help here if possible

Comment: That error is telling you the problem, there is no table called `PRODTABLE` in the database you are connected to, on the default schema for the `USER` you are connected as; we can't tell you what the correct name should be. You also alias your second subquery as `PM` and then `JOIN` to the table `PRODTABLE` and alias it as `PM`; that isn't allowed either.

Comment: @Larnu

i did remove the joint and use the below :
`
SELECT 
    [SEASON],
    SUM(BL.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY,
    PM.PRODUCT AS 'PRD_CLASS',
    PM.BRAND AS 'BRAND',
    PM.COST_PRICE AS 'COST',
    PM.DATECREATE   
FROM
    (SELECT
         QUANTITY, WAREHOUSE,
         CASE SUBSTRING(EXTENDED, 3, 1)
             WHEN '1' THEN 'SS'
             ELSE 'FW'
         END + SUBSTRING (EXTENDED, 1, 2) [SEASON]
     FROM 
         BINLABEL WITH (NOLOCK)
    ) BL WHERE 
    WAREHOUSE = '0001'
GROUP BY 
    [SEASON]
ORDER BY 
    [SEASON]

Comment: my issue am unable to join the other table, and when you kindly advice to remove the From and replace with CROSS JOIN, honestly i don't know which FROM i should remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, you have 2 `FROM` clauses. Presumably the latter should be a `CROSS JOIN` or `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` (we don't know which). You also alias your second derived table as `PM` and then alias the table `PRODTABLE` as `PM`; that isn't allowed either as you can't have 2 objects with the same alias in the same scope. As I can't guess what alias you mean in other locations, I put `{Alias}` in places you need to add the relevant alias.

I also remove the `NOLOCK` table hints; you didn't reply as to why you "need" them and with respect I doubt you understand what it does considering the comments and question; more likely you have picked up someone elses terrible habit (get rid of said bad habit now).

I also, finally, get rid of the other bad habit of single quote aliases (see my comment on that too) and schema qualify (assuming `dbo`):

```sql
SELECT {Alias}.[SEASON],
       SUM(BL.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY,
       {Alias}.PRODUCT AS PRD_CLASS,
       {Alias}.BRAND AS BRAND,
       {Alias}.COST_PRICE AS COST,
       {Alias}.DATECREATE
FROM (SELECT QUANTITY,
             WAREHOUSE,
             CASE SUBSTRING(EXTENDED, 3, 1)WHEN '1' THEN 'SS' ELSE 'FW' END + SUBSTRING(EXTENDED, 1, 2) AS [SEASON]
      FROM dbo.BINLABE) BL
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT PRODUCT AS PRDODUCT,
                        BRAND AS BRAND,
                        COST_PRICE AS COST,
                        DATECREATE AS DATE_CREATE
                 FROM dbo.PRODTABLE) PT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.PRODTABLE PM ON BL.SKU = PM.SKU --Think we can safely assume this is PM
WHERE {Alias}.WAREHOUSE = '0001'
GROUP BY {Alias}.[SEASON]
ORDER BY {Alias}.[SEASON];
```

Comment: I really really appreciated your kind patience and value all your advice, someone taught me to always use NOLOCK if I use SQL server and the Alias as well, thx again for your time and support

Comment: *"someone taught me to always use NOLOCK "* That person taught you a terrible habit, @YoussiMizrahi ; especially if they didn't explain what it does (and no, "it's a magic go faster button" isn't what it does). Always *aliasing* is good, but the problem was you used the *same* alias twice in the same scope.

Comment: am trying to find the best course or website to develop my knowledge in SQL, am googling most of my time :)